# Unable to install GitHub Extension for repositories in Visual Studio

Tags: github, windows-installer, visual-studio-extensions

1. Downloaded the extension file (GitHub.VisualStudio.vsix) file from microsoft visual studio website (https://visualstudio.github.com/ )
2. The visual studio using is the VS2013
3. There is the problem installation saying the "SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied"

[image: VSIX Installer error on executing GitHub.VisualStudio.vsix in Windows10]

The install log goes like this:

```html
4/16/2016 12:18:52 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
4/16/2016 12:18:52 PM - -------------------------------------------
4/16/2016 12:18:52 PM - Initializing Install...
4/16/2016 12:18:53 PM - Extension Details...
4/16/2016 12:18:53 PM -  Identifier      : c3d3dc68-c977-411f-b3e8-03b0dccf7dfc
4/16/2016 12:18:53 PM -  Name            : GitHub Extension for Visual Studio
4/16/2016 12:18:53 PM -  Author          : GitHub, Inc
4/16/2016 12:18:53 PM -  Version         : 1.0.18.2
4/16/2016 12:18:53 PM -  Description     : A Visual Studio Extension that brings the GitHub Flow into Visual Studio.
4/16/2016 12:18:53 PM -  Locale          : en-US
4/16/2016 12:18:53 PM -  MoreInfoURL     : https://visualstudio.github.com/
4/16/2016 12:18:53 PM -  InstalledByMSI  : False
4/16/2016 12:18:53 PM -  SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
4/16/2016 12:18:53 PM - 
4/16/2016 12:18:53 PM - System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignedInfo(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignature(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignature(X509Certificate2 certificate, Boolean verifySignatureOnly)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.XmlDigitalSignatureProcessor.Verify(X509Certificate2 signer)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackageDigitalSignature.Verify(X509Certificate signingCertificate)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackageDigitalSignature.Verify()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallableExtensionImpl.GetSignatureState(ZipPackage vsixPackage)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallableExtensionImpl.get_SignatureState()
   at VSIXInstaller.App.LogExtensionDetails(IExtension extension)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: You might want to contact GitHub support if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Visual Studio 2013. Apparently this extension requires **Visual Studio 2015 or newer**:

[image]

You can find additional details in the [README.md](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio#github-extension-for-visual-studio) file on the GitHub [page](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio) of the project:

> The GitHub Extension for Visual Studio provides GitHub integration in **Visual Studio 2015**.